# Strange encoding issue in PHP

Tags: php, encode

I have been banging my head in the wall for couple of hours, I still couldn't figure out the issue. I have an associative array and when I try to build a query with it, It shows weird characters in the browser.

```
$reportVars = [
            "__report" => "alpha",
            "start_date" => "2001",
            "end_date" => "2002",
            "dsp_id" => "SPP",
            "current_sp_id" => "SPP_1",
            "sp_name" => "fawzan"

        ];

print_r(http_build_query($reportVars));
```

This is the output I get in the browser

```
__report=alpha&start_date=2001&end_date=2002&dsp_id=SPP¤t_sp_id=SPP_1&sp_name=fawzan
```

Note the strange character (¤) in the output after **SPP**, Before you ask No, I did not copy it from anywhere. I just typed it with my bare hand.

Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: try changing the sequence of the variable? plz tell me if it makes any diff

Comment: I tried that as well.  I moved the current_sp_id around, No luck :/

Comment: it happens for current_sp_id or anyword after spp?

Comment: Strange, If I remove the 'n' in the 'current_sp_id' no problem occurs. :/

Comment: try changing the double quotes to single

Comment: also, type it again manually, not copy paste

Comment: @NabeelKhan I tried the single quote, did not work. And as I have mentioned in the question I never copy pasted it. I typed it.

Comment: In Java "&curren" is encoded to "¤"

Comment: this is PHP, any way I will try something.

Comment: use urlencode() outside the query

Comment: or making curren... variable the first one in the result can be an option too

Comment: P.S. the issue isn't with php, it was being treated that way by browser as per my understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

&curren is being converted to ¤

you may have few options now:

1. move the `current_sp_id` to top, making it the first variable so that there is no `&` before it
2. use `&amp` as separator instead of `&` only by using:

   `print_r(http_build_query($reportVars, '', '& amp;'));`

(remove the space between `&` and `amp`, added it because it's being converted to & only here too).

P.S. php isn't causing this issue as per my understanding, it's how your browser treats &curren by probably converting it to ¤ itself